# How to get a image form django imageFile input

Tags: python, django

I want to get the image from the `ImageField` file input and then display the image in a template, and finally save the image to the model `imageField`.

The `file_image = request.POST.get('image')` only gets the image name, how do I get the actual image. Do I need to upload the image to a `NamedTemporaryFile()` first?

**view**

```
def uploadImageView(request):
    form = UploadImageForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid:
            file_image = request.POST.get('image')
            request.session['file_image'] = file_image
            return redirect('image:create')


def saveImageView(request):
    uploaded_image = request.session.get('file_image')

    form = Form(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None,)

    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form_create.save(commit=False)
        instance.image = uploaded_image
        inastance.save()
```

**Template**

**First views template**

```
  <form method="POST" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit"></input>
    {{ form }}
  </form>
```

**second views template**

```
  <form method="POST" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
  <input type="submit"></input>
  </form>

  {{ form.instance.image.url }}
```

Comment: No you can not save image using request.POST.get('image'). Instead of that use request.FILES.get('image') or forms.cleaned_data.get('image') to save the image.

Comment: Thanks for the comment i tried your solutions but i get 'None'.

Comment: add 'enctype=multipart/form-data' in your <form> .

Comment: Thanks, however now i get a error TypeError: <InMemoryUploadedFile: image.jpg (image/jpeg)> is not JSON serializable

Comment: why are you using two views to save the uploaded image. You can save the uploaded image in only one view.

Comment: Because i want to show the selected image in the template. so i would have to get the image first and then show it in the second view otherwise it says the ImageField has nothing selected. and can't show {{ form.instance.image.url }}.

Answer (score 2):

To get the images inputted in your html file,
use:

```
request.FILES["input name "]
```

Answer (score 1):

To upload a file, you need to add `enctype='multipart/form-data'` to your HTML form. So your form should look like:

```
  <form method="POST" action="" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit"></input>
    {{ form }}
  </form>
```

and in your views, you need to access `request.FILES` to get the uploaded file. Your upload image view should be:

```
def uploadImageView(request):
    form = UploadImageForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            # rest of the code.
```