# Django: how to save image in django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

i am trying to save image in django, but it seems not to be working as expected and i can't really tell what is going with the code. the the way i am submitting the form is not a straight forward way of doing `form.save` but i am trying to create a topic, if there is no existing topic from the drop down, other informations get saved but the image does not get saved.

views.py

```
@login_required
def CreateRoom(request):
    topics = Topic.objects.all()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ChatRoomForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        topic_name = request.POST.get("topic")
        topic , created = Topic.objects.get_or_create(name = topic_name )
        
        new_room = Chatroom.objects.create(
            ...
            image = request.POST.get("image" )
            ...
        )
```

Comment: isn't this similar? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45096242/how-to-get-a-image-form-django-imagefile-input

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a image form django imageFile input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45096242/how-to-get-a-image-form-django-imagefile-input)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must take image from request.FILES, after write this into storage then set image path into your model field